# Display part of django model in html table

Tags: python, django

How to display only some columns of Django model in a HTML template?
And also: how do I perform a function on one of the records? (amount)?
Right now I'm displaying a whole table of model like that:

my `models.py`

```
class Tabela(models.Model):
block_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
type =  models.CharField(max_length=32)
link =  models.CharField(max_length=64)
link_as_account =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
account =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
amount =  models.CharField(max_length=64)

def __str__(self):
    return self.block_id
```

My `views.py`

```
def search_results(request):
model = Tabela
query_addresse = request.GET.get('addressee', None)
query_hash = request.GET.get('hash', None)

if not query_hash and not query_addresse and request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'nanosite/index.html', {})

if query_hash and request.method == 'GET':
    if query_addresse:
        result = Tabela.objects.filter(account=query_addresse, block_id=query_hash)
    else:
        result = Tabela.objects.filter(block_id=query_hash)
    field_names = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields()]
    data = [[getattr(ins, name) for name in field_names]
            for ins in result]

elif query_addresse and request.method == 'GET':
    result = Tabela.objects.filter(account=query_addresse)
    field_names = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields()]
    data = [[getattr(ins, name) for name in field_names]
            for ins in result]
return render(request, 'nanosite/index.html', {'field_names': field_names, 'data': data})
```

My `index.html`

```
        <div id="bottomhalf" class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                {% for head in field_names %}
                   <th scope="col">{{ head }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for row in data %}
                    <tr scope="row">
                        {% for cell in row %}
                            <td>{{ cell }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

What I'd like to do is display only `block_id`, `timestamp`, `account` and `amount` in html. I've tried different approaches like using only the result part of views without field_names and data, but of course it didn't work.

My other question is, how can I modify the field `amount` and perform an operation on it to be displayed in template like amound divided by certain digit with a $ sign before it (for example if amount=1488 to be divided by 124 and displayed as '$12')?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/

Answer (score 1):

Pass the queryset `qs` selecting the objects to display to the template and iterate over it to generate your table:

```
{% for obj in qs %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{obj.block_id}} </td>
        <!-- etc ... -->
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, if you also want to pass a variable specifying the names of the fields of the object to tabulate, and in what order, you find out that the Django template engine is *by design* (!) incapable of doing that. You can either do what you are doing, and generate a list-of-rows in Python which you pass to the Template, or you need a Django [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) such as

```
@register.filter
def attr( obj, name): 
    return getattr( obj, name, '')
```

and then you can run an inner loop in your template

```
<tr>
{% for name in selected_field_names %}
   <td> {{obj|attr:name}} </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

The answer to the second question, is to define a property on your model to return the field suitably transmogrified:

```
class Tabela(models.Model):
...
    @property
    def funny_amount(self):
        val = self.amount/12.0
        return f'$ {val:.2f}'
```

and refer to `{{obj.funny_amount}}` in your template